# Changing input button to images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to JavaScript.
I am having trouble changing the show button and hide button to images instead.
The show button will be a different image to the hide button.
How would I go about doing this?

https://jsfiddle.net/ej0r4amd/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#collapse").slideToggle("slow");
    if ($(this).val() == "Hide")
      $(this).val("Show");
    else
      $(this).val("Hide");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Hide" id="button">
<div id="collapse">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: Does your question look nicely formatted and readable to you?

Comment: No, but I am confused on how to use the code tags

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted has anything to do with making buttons be images.

Comment: As I said, I am new to javascript I tried google and found nothing helpful. The best I found was using one fixed image but I can do this by changing button to image in input tag

Comment: So you just want the buttons to look like images?

Comment: I want to remove them with images yes. One for hide and one for show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use the `<input type="image">` and change the `src` attribute using `.attr("src"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#collapse").slideToggle("slow");
    if ($(this).val() == "Hide") {
      $(this).val("Show");
      $(this).attr("src","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d35f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
    } else {
      $(this).val("Hide");
      $(this).attr("src","https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" value="Hide" id="button" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2e83e2d00f0b889da7d5905c7bf574c2?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"></button>
<div id="collapse">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: The Hello World doesn't get hidden though?

Comment: That was because you had a syntax error when setting the `id="collapse "` which should have been `id="collapse"` I fixed that too now.

Comment: Yes, I changed it after the edit . Thanks!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: When I refresh the page it returns to  the first image. Is there any code which stores the last clicked image?

Comment: You can use cookies.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+use+cookies+javascript&ia=web

Comment: Hello, I get an error on W3 html validator because of value="" on input which isn't allowed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do what you want.

You could use an img tag and onClick change the `src` value

You could use an element ( eg span ) and on click change backgroundImage property.

Or, like in the example below, use an element and on click toggle the className and in css add different background-image for each className

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger").on("click", function() {
    $("#collapse").slideToggle("slow");

    $(this).toggleClass('show', 'hide')

  });
});
```

```css
.trigger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.hide {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/50x50")
}

.show {
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/100x100")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="trigger hide"></span>
<div id="collapse">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: How can I use cookies to remember the last clicked image?

Comment: You can use localstorage to remember the last clicked and get it on page load

Comment: Could you show me how to do it with Timothy Alexis Vass's code?

Comment: You should ask him to help you. Or post a different question as this requirement ( save to localstorate/cookies ) was not in the original question. Or better yet, search it your self on google. It's very VERY simple to store/get data from localstorage .Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a class, and then control the background image of the button with a class—in this case: `.show`.

You had forgotten a quotation mark on `type="button"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#collapse").slideToggle("slow");
    
    if ($(this).val() == "Hide") {
      $(this).val("Show");
      $(this).toggleClass("show");
    } else {
      $(this).val("Hide");
      $(this).toggleClass("show");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#button {
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/50/50");
}

#button.show {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/20/50/50");
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Hide" id="button">
<div id="collapse">
Hello World
</div>
```